# How to declear a class static property default value as array in php's c extension?

Tags: php, c

How to declear a class **static** property(**default value: an array**) in php's c extension?
Code:

```
zval httpStatuses;

array_init(&httpStatuses);

zend_declare_property ( cheetah_web_response_ce, "httpStatuses",strlen ( "httpStatuses" ), &httpStatuses, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC|ZEND_ACC_STATIC TSRMLS_CC );
```

It shows the error following when i compile:

```
Fatal error - Internal zval's can't be arrays, objects or resources
```

It can be initialized in __construct function if it not a static property.
So,I need help,Thanks!